# Customise Drupal 7 Taxonomy View / Template (without module)

Tags: taxonomy-terms, theming

How would I go about changing a custom taxonomy view / template without using a module?

i.e. I have a taxonomy named 'tutorials' which has three posts.

How would I modify the HTML output for 'tutorials?

From what I've heard, you can create a file named 'taxonomy--name.tpl.php' to override the default taxonomy template?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As described in [Drupal 7 Theme Hook Suggestions](http://drupal.org/node/1089656), the template files that Drupal looks for a taxonomy term page are the following:

- taxonomy-term--[tid].tpl.php
- taxonomy-term--[vocabulary-machine-name].tpl.php
- taxonomy-term.tpl.php

Replace *[tid]* with the taxonomy term ID, and *[vocabulary-machine-name]* with the machine name set for the vocabulary. Supposing that the machine name is programming_languages, then the template filename that Drupal looks is taxonomy-term--programming-languages.tpl.php. (The underscores are replaced with hyphens.)

The first file that is found is the one that Drupal uses.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, if you don't want to use any module, but are fine to carve in your PHP templates, then this [taxonomy.module API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.module/7) is what you need. We could probably come up with more detailed help  if you described your goal more precisely.

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite output in Views, and change Style (the HTML containers and classes) for each.

Did you mean without create a custom module? If so, there are several contrib taxonomy modules out there:

Taxonomy Formatter -- lets you add HTML wrappers around element and container
Taxonomy Page Display -- create custom taxonomy page for each term (or certain terms)
Display Suite - let you customize dang near any node or form