# Customizing the Tag page shown by default in Drupal 7

Tags: taxonomy-terms, meta-tags

I made a field in one of my content types as Tags. On the site, they are shown as follows:-

**mytag_1, mytag_2, mytag_3.**. When I click on either of them, they show me all the pages which are tagged with the clicked tag. How is it doing is beyond me, as I didn't even enable the view.

This is the URL it uses:-
www.mysite.com/tags/mytag_1

Now, my question is how can I customise it. Now it uses node.tpl.php and shows all the pages. I wanna change the layout but don't know how to, as I don't know how these pages are generated.

I also tried making pages as node--tags.tpl.php but to no avail.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ideal way to customize the tags pages(www.mysite.com/tags/mytag_1) is to enable the view "Taxonomy term" and then customize it the way you need it. As you might already know Views provides much more flexibility and easy to customize.

If you do not want to use Views and only want to update the template then refer to the [link](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/34067/customise-drupal-7-taxonomy-view-template-without-module)

Comment: I'd love to do that but when even when I make a view, it doesn't take over to my usual page. My page is currently showing all the matching nodes, and it doesn't accept my view when I do have the Path as `/tags/%`

Comment: The path for the taxonomy page should be /taxonomy/term/% by default. Is this intentionally modified by you?